# Trying to wrap text called from DB in <p> tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm pretty new to php and I can't figure out why 'testimonial_text' is not being wrapped within the 'testimonial-text' class. For some reason, it's outputting 3 elements and one of them is "testimonial text" but it's not within the "testimonial-text". "testimonial_author" is being correctly wrapped in "testimonial-author". Any ideas?

```
  <?php

    $rows = get_field('testimonials');

    if($rows) {
      foreach($rows as $row) {
        $output = "<div class = 'testimonial-container'>";
        $output .= "<p class = 'testimonial-text'>".$row['testimonial_text'] . "</p>";
        $output .= "<p class = 'testimonial-author'>".$row['testimonial_author'] . "</p>";
        $output .= "</div>";
        echo $output;
      }
    }

  ?>
```

Comment: What are the values from the data?  What is the resulting output?

Comment: try filtered or senitize the value by `filter_var` or `strip_tags`.

Comment: Can you please var_dump($rows) and show us the results - and also show the generated html code, thanks.

Comment: @SimonPollard is this what you're talking about by var_dump($rows)?  http://uploadpie.com/QJSXZ

Comment: Yes thanks... the only thing that looks odd to me there is the quotes. Try wrapping your $row['name'] outputs in strip_tags() function as @Naumov says. So `strip_tags($row['testimonial_text'])` etc... and see what happens. I tried using a dummy array and your code is fine. So I think is the data in that array causing issues.

Comment: @SimonPollard you're exactly right. I'm doing this in WordPress and I think everything that is echoed is automatically wrapped in a <p>. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Good stuff - added an answer for you with slightly updated code (to make better use of $output - credit to @Naumov as well

Answer (score 1):

Following the image showing the contents of $rows in the comments it looks like the data you are returning has extra code and/or quotes in it. So I would recommend doing something like..

```
if($rows) {
      $output = '';
      foreach($rows as $row) {
        $output .= "<div class = 'testimonial-container'>";
        $output .= "<p class = 'testimonial-text'>" . strip_tags ($row['testimonial_text']) . "</p>";
        $output .= "<p class = 'testimonial-author'>" . strip_tags ($row['testimonial_author']) . "</p>";
        $output .= "</div>";
      }
      echo $output;
}
```

To remove any stray code that is getting output.

Worth noting @Naumov said to use strip_tags as well :)

Comment: I think `$output = null` this php notice, because not string and batter for me `$output=''`...

Comment: Fair enough - I have updated the answer. The main thing is to declare output else you can trigger php warnings using .= before an item exists :)